# Addin text on images using html - multiple images within a div element?

Tags: html, css

I need to overlay text and images over both basic-b1.png and basic-b2.png. How would I achieve this so that it's easy to accurately position the text and images?

I do understand how to add text on images when there is only one image within the div element. However when there are two images and they both have to be center aligned with each other I cannot separate out the images into different div elements.

CSS:

```
   .bun{
         text-align:center;
         position:relative
      }
```

HTML :

```
   <div class="bun">
        <img src="basic-b1.png" height ="320" width ="212"> 
        <span style="padding-left:200px"></span>
        <img src="basic-b2.png" height ="320" width ="212">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ::hover selector is usually used in such cases

Html:

```
<div class="bun">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1538497508301-aa6452af8400?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=ca19176e4dc2bcc9269edf74c9c10d4f" height ="320" width ="212"> 
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521624928109-a794da7909a9?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ&s=48e97751d49c36e90b877ab2bbe27c3e" height ="320" width ="212">
   </div>
```

Css:

```
.bun{
         text-align:center;
         position:relative
}

.bun::before {
  content: 'hi there';
  color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
  left: 40%;
  top: 40%;
}
```

You can place an image instead of text by doing `content: 'url(...)'`.
If you need different imgs/texts for each img, you would have to wrap them in another div and put the ::before selector on those because the img tag doesn't accept ::before.